# cant use variables from gamedig onembed

Tags: javascript, gamedig

**im working on a status bot but  can't use variables from the game state in my embed, its not showing when im try to put it on the  description**

**here it's my code
I edited the code**

**The whole code is like this**

````
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const yaml = require("js-yaml");
const Gamedig = require('gamedig');
const supportbot = yaml.load(
  fs.readFileSync("./Configs/supportbot.yml", "utf8")
);
const cmdconfig = yaml.load(fs.readFileSync("./Configs/commands.yml", "utf8"));

const Command = require("../Structures/Command.js");
const { timeStamp } = require("console");
var request = require('request');


const jugadores = state.players.length;


setInterval(() => {
  // query your game server
  Gamedig.query({
    type: 'minecraft',
    host: 'mc.latinplay.net',
    port: '25565'
  })
  .then((updatedState) => {
    state = updatedState;
  });
}, 6000); 



let state = null;


module.exports = new Command({
  name: cmdconfig.EstadoCommand,
  description: cmdconfig.EstadoCommandDesc,


  async run(interaction) {



      const LatinEstado = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
    .setColor('RANDOM') ```
    .setDescription("Users:", jugadores)
````

Comment: Are the variables you're referring to `joueursmax` and `jugadores`? Because those are both declared in an inner scope and immediately go out of scope right after being defined and assigned.

Comment: yes, im referring to ```jugadores``` and ```joueursmax```  how can i solved?

Comment: Declare them outside the block, the way you do with `state`.

Comment: i'll try like, im new to javascript, console err says ```ReferenceError: Cannot access 'state' before initialization```

Comment: You should move the declarations up above the setInterval call.

Comment: i did it, but its still says the same err, i edited the code and put the whole code

Comment: You are trying to access `state` before you define it. You need to move its declaration up. Also, I don't think you want `jugadores` to be `const`; that means it can never change.

Comment: can you give a quick example of it? im really new to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `state` variable has to be declared *before* you use it. The `jugadores` variable cannot be `const` if you want it to change.

```
let state = null;

let jugadores = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  // query your game server
  Gamedig.query({
    type: 'minecraft',
    host: 'mc.latinplay.net',
    port: '25565'
  })
  .then((updatedState) => {
    state = updatedState;
    jugadores = state.players.length;
  });
}, 6000);
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. i have a newbie error and ```its   if (typeof data !== 'string') throw new error(errorMessage);
                                        
RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.```


my embed code on field its, im trying to call **jugadores**

    .addField('**Jugadores:**', jugadores, true)

Comment: @AleShito Sorry, I don't know anything about Gamedig or Minecraft. You should ask a new question about that.